# E_DEFAULT_LOCALE_NOT_DEFINED: Default locale has not been defined. - Globalize

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Quando eu digito 1 número no input aparece esse erro:

> E_DEFAULT_LOCALE_NOT_DEFINED: Default locale has not been defined.

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei várias formas e nada. Segue código:

**Model:**

```
public class Teste
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Data:")]
    [AssertThat("DeadLine >= Today()", ErrorMessage = "* Data deverá ser superior a data de hoje")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo Data é obrigatório")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DeadLine, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeadLine, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/message.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/plural.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/currency.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/relative-time.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
```

**Web.config:**

```
<system.web>
  <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
</system.web>
```

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Isso é uma exceção do JavaScript, né?

Comment: @LINQ isso mesmo

Comment: Só por curiosidade essa `View` que adicionou na pergunta é uma página `Mestre`?

Comment: @Marconi ela não é.

Comment: Me parece que tenho que utilizar algum tipo de "cldr"

Answer (score -2):

I solved my problem when I see that the port used in my application is different from IIS.

My application used port default (80), but I need used port :81.

I changed the Mine type in my IIS.

Comment: Traduza a sua resposta para português.